# Asp.Net Core - How to use the amount of input in the loop with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I Have a Input tag in Html :

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-5">                           
     <input asp-for="CountSlide" class="form-control" value="2"/>                      
     <a id="add-slide" class="btn btn-info m-t-5" href="#">Add</a>
 </div>
```

And I Have A Loop in Razor View :

```
@for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
         <div class="form-group">                               
           <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" class="form-control">                                
         </div>
       }
```

I want to use the input value in the loop ("count") when the add button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## NEWEST

You can put your `@for` code in partial view.

[image]

[How to use jquery or ajax to update razor partial view in c#/asp.net for a MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392212/how-to-use-jquery-or-ajax-to-update-razor-partial-view-in-c-asp-net-for-a-mvc-p/19410973#19410973)

---

*You want the following div in `@for (int i = 0; i <count; i++)` to render elements according to the value in the input, which is impossible.*

**You only can do it by javascript, not use razor engine.**

Related Post: [What is the order of execution of the C# in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550097/what-is-the-order-of-execution-of-the-c-sharp-in-razor)

The simple explanation is that when you can see all the contents of the page, the back-end C# code will no longer be executed.

#### PRIVIOUS

You can use @count to get the value.

[image]

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    int count = 5;
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    function readURL(url) {
        alert(url)
    }
    function func() {
        var get_count = @count;
        alert(get_count);
        //$.ajax({
        //    url: "url",
        //    type: "POST",
        //    data: {a:"a"},
        //    success: function (veri) {
        //        console.log("success");
        //    },
        //    error: function (hata, ajaxoptions, throwerror) {
        //        alert("failed");
        //    }
        //});
    }

</script>

<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <input  class="form-control" value="2" />
    <a id="add-slide" class="btn btn-info m-t-5" href="#"  onclick="func()">Add</a>
</div>

<hr />

@for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" class="form-control">
    </div>
}
```

Comment: thanks but I want to getting value from Input

Comment: it's posible I send the value to the controller and pass it to view again with ajax??

Comment: Yes, you can put your `@for` code in partial view. https://i.imgur.com/J8nIN8t.png

Comment: The photo did not open for me